# Switching between 2 windows in selenium webdriver with java

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, browser

I am automating an application using selenium webdriver with java. In that i have to open a browser instance & perform some actions. After that i have to open another browser instance, perform some actions in it & close that instance. Then i have to return the control back to the first browser instance again to perform some other actions.

I tried using :

```
String winHandleBefore = driver.getWindowHandle();
//then open new instance and perfom the actions
driver.switchTo().window(winHandleBefore);
```

But this returned an error :

`org.openqa.selenium.remote.SessionNotFoundException: no such session`

How can i do this? Can anybody help?

Comment: How did you open and close the new window?

Comment: Opened new window by : System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "D:\\MyProjects\\SeleniumTrials\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");
      driver= new ChromeDriver();
     driver.get(properties.getProperty("VAR_ADMINURL"));
     driver.manage().window().maximize();                                  Closed by : driver.close();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you did `driver = new ChromeDriver();` you reinitialized the `driver` object, which caused the lost of the first window. You can see it by checking the number of window handles after opening the new window

```
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
int len = getWindowHandles().size(); // 1 as expected
driver = new ChromeDriver();
len = getWindowHandles().size(); // still 1, has only the new window
```

To solve this use temporary `driver` to open the new window

```
WebDriver tempDriver = new ChromeDriver();
// do some stuff
tempDriver.close();
```